# I can not seem to get an img to fit it's div parent's width

Tags: html, css

I need to use an image that will resize with the text I want to layover it. Using width:100%; only fills about half the page. max-width:100%; fills even less. I have confirmed with borders that the parent is filling the space I want the img to fill. The img css is at the bottom of the css. I can not seem to find this exact issue online.

Update: I found the solution. So simple, I just needed to flex direction column. Since the problem was 2divs sharing the same space. Rookie move :)

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"> 

<head>
<title>Berry Wild's Pizzaria</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/about.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="main" style="background-image: url('img/pizzaalien.png');">
 <h1>All About Berry Wild's Pizzaria</h1>

<ul class="mainmenu" style="background-image: url('img/menubackground.png');">
<li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="order.html">Order</a></li>
<li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>

</div>



<div class="about-base">

    <div class="mainsection">
    <img src="img/john.png">
    <p>
    Many people have worked on ways to deliver pizza to space travelers. We find 
simplest option is to send one of the pizzas directly to the astronaut's home from the 
moon or an asteroid through a wormhole or portal. This would save time and transport gas 
for the trip. Other methods of delivery include using a flying saucer or even a 
helicopter train system. Some have even proposed sending individual slices via rocket-
```

powered ice shiver units. However, astronauts must factor in environmental conditions
when planning meals away from Earth.  With us you worry no longer.

```
    Being far from Earth can make people feel hungry; pizzas are easy to prepare and are 
good calorie sources. Plus, astronauts spend most of their time in spacesuits that don't 
properly cook foods beyond their required temperatures. Our food shippers can send pre-
```

cooked cooked pizzas that don't require any cooking by the astronauts themselves except
for heating them up before eating them.

```
</div>

</body>



</html>
```

CSS

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=VT323&display=swap');


*
{padding:0; margin:0;}

html
{
width:100%;
height:100%;    
}
body
{
display:flex;
width:100%;
height:100%;
flex-wrap: wrap;
background-size:contain;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center; 
}


div.main
{
/* border:green 2px solid; */
width:100%;
height:400px;
display:flex;
flex-direction: column;

}

h1
{
/* border: purple 2px solid; */
width: 100%;
height: 67%;
font-family: 'Silkscreen', cursive;
font-size: 82px;
color: DarkMagenta;
text-shadow: 0 0 5px crimson, 0 0 7px crimson, 0 0 5px gold, 0 0 5px gold, 0 0 12px 
magenta, 0 0 12px magenta, 0 0 20px lime, 0 0 20px lime, 0 0 17px lime;
margin-top: 80px;
text-align: center;
}

ul.mainmenu
{
border:MediumVioletRed 5px solid;
border-style: inset;
display:flex;
background-repeat:repeat;
background-size:contain;
height:60px;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}

li
{
border: OrangeRed 6px solid;

border-radius:5px;
border-image:linear-gradient(90deg,red,blue,green,yellow);
border-image-slice:1;
background-color:DarkMagenta;
width: 160px;
list-style: none;
font-size: 42px;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
}

li a
{
text-decoration:none;
color:lime;
text-shadow:0 0 2px LimeGreen,0 0 3px LimeGreen,0 0 4px LimeGreen;
font-family:'Silkscreen', cursive;
}

div.about-base
{
border:purple 3px solid;
display: flex;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width:100%;
height:967px;
align-self:center;
background-size:contain;
}



div.about-base section
{
/* border:cyan 2px solid; */
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

div.about-base div.mainsection
{
border:red 2px solid;
display:flex;
width:100%;
height:100%;
justify-content:center;
}

div.about-base div.mainsection p
{
/* border: cyan 2px solid; */
color:red;
font-size: 23px;
text-shadow:1px 1px #60196c,1px 1px 3px #60196c;
position:relative;
font-family: 'Amatic SC', cursive;
width:48%;
height:36%;
top:232px;
right:370px;
}

div.about-base div.mainsection img
{
border:green 2px solid;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Your image and the container may well have different aspect-ratios so showing the img at 100% width will probably not have the right height to fill the container. Look into object-fit: cover Please also check the code as it looks in  your question and make it into a runnable snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).